# Badges don't show color on mobile user page, but do on badge page

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, mobile-web

When looking at my badges, there is no dot to indicate if it's a gold, silver, or bronze badge. Consider the Xcode badge below:

[image: colorless badges]

However, when viewing the badge on its own page, colors are shown:

[image: colored badge]

I'm using Safari mobile on an iPhone 4, running iOS 5.0.1.

Is this a bug? Intentional?

Comment: I experience the same on my Android browwser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was definitely a <s>bug</s> feature, it will be <s>fixed</s> *removed per your request* everywhere in the profile with the next build.

Comment: I wasn't requesting that it be removed per sé, but either way works. I just think that consistency is important.